# Will my previous votes increase the publicly displayed post score after I achieve 15 reputation?

Tags: support, voting, new-users

While I have less than 15 reputation the following notification is shown every time I click to an upvote

[image]

I suppose this recorded information is used for community statistics and most-important sort of questions and answer. *However it would be nice to give my vote contribution for those who taken my doubts out.*

Since this privilege is earned the already-given votes are also counted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you would have to cast the vote again after you reach 15 rep, since your vote wasn't actually a full/normal vote. See [Once I reach 15 reputation, will my old votes be taken into account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285181/307535) for more.

My suggestion at this point would be to "favorite" (star) the corresponding question(s) to make it easier to rediscover them when you can vote.